# Custom exceptions to Http status codes in ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes, custom-exceptions

I have a couple of custom exceptions in my business layer that bubble up to my API methods in my ASP.NET application.

Currently, they all translate to Http status 500. How do I map these custom exceptions so that I could return different Http status codes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible using [Response.StatusCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx) setter and getter.

**Local Exception handling:** For local action exception handling, put the following inside the calling code.

```
var responseCode = Response.StatusCode;
try
{
    // Exception was called
}
catch (BusinessLayerException1)
{
    responseCode = 201
}
catch (BusinessLayerException2)
{
    responseCode = 202
}
Response.StatusCode = responseCode;
```

**For cross controller behavior:** You should follow the below procedure.

1. Create a abstract BaseController
2. Make your current Controllers inherit from BaseController.
3. Add the following logic inside BaseController.

**BaseController.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var responseCode = Response.StatusCode;
        var exception = filterContext.Exception;
        switch (exception.GetType().ToString())
        {
            case "ArgumentNullException":
                responseCode = 601;
                break;

            case "InvalidCastException":
                responseCode = 602;
                break;
        }
        Response.StatusCode = responseCode;
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Note:**
You can also add the exception as handled and redirecting it into some other **Controller/Action**

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
filterContext.Result = this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Error");
```

**More Information** concerning ASP.NET MVC Error handling can be found [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine)

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. One follow up question: where can I put this so that I don't have to repeat this logic in every API method?

Comment: @Sam, Edited my code, For next time, please state those request at initial post.